# Is there any way to get a unicode character that has a byte of 23?

Tags: binary-code, unicode, ssrf

I am pentesting a web application. It makes a backend call to another application, and I am trying to hijack that call.

I have gained control over the URL path, query parameters, and fragment that is being sent (e.g. if the URL is `https://internal-app.com/` I can make it `https://internal-app.com/whatever-path-I-want?also=queryparameters#andthefragment`). But one of the query parameters is added automatically by the application, no matter what I do, and I'm trying to strip that query parameter.

I've discovered that the internal application interprets each byte of a unicode character as its own character (for example, with `Ē`, `U+0112`, which has a hex representation in `UTF-8` of `C4 92`, the application interprets each byte separately, and `C4 92` becomes `Ä’`, despite the fact that `Ē` was sent). I'm trying to exploit this bug to send the fragment symbol, `#`, without the first application realizing it (because if it realizes it, it adds the query parameter before the fragment).

So I need a unicode character with at least one hex byte of 23 (`#=U+0023`). But this seems to be impossible, as according to the Wikipedia page for UTF-8, in all characters that have multiple bytes, the bytes start with 10 (and the binary for `#` is `00100011`).

Am I right in thinking that this is impossible? And if so, should I try a different encoding for the URL, or is there another character that I could try exploiting? (I've already tried the null byte, it rejects all requests with a null byte for security reasons.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [UTF-8 wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding), you will not be able to send a byte that would be interpreted as a # on its own as part of a larger UTF character. The chart showing the encoding structure verifies this.

Have you tested to see if the query parameter is triggered whenever # appears in the query, or only the first time? You might be able to send enough #'s to get one to appear in the url. I'm assuming that the site is encoding the # itself in the url. It's my understanding that a raw # would cause the subsequent portion of the URL to remain client-side only, no matter where it appears.

Comment: Yes, that's my goal. I'm trying to include a hash before the query parameter so that it gets ignored. Fragments are supposed to remain client-side, but even if you do send one to the server, it ignores it, to account for a badly configured client. The query parameter appears no matter what I do.

Comment: Can you add the query parameter yourself with malformed data?

Comment: I did try to do that, yes, but it still won't be stripped. (?queryParameter=myData&queryParameter=applicationData, which then gets interpreted as myData,applicationData and that's not helpful).